# preserving the order of returning entities when using .Contains(Id)

Tags: linq, entity-framework, ef-code-first, code-first

I want to hydrate a collection of entities by passing in a List of Ids and also preserve the order.

Another SO answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/15187081/1059911 suggested this approach to hydrating the entities which works great

```
var entities = db.MyEntities.Where(e => myListOfIds.Contains(e.ID)).ToList();
```

however the order of entities in the collection is different from the order of Ids

Is there a way to preserve the order?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

May be that helps:

```
var entities = db.MyEntities
    .Where(e => myListOfIds.Contains(e.ID))
    .OrderBy(e => myListOfIds.IndexOf(e.ID)).ToList();
```

**EDIT**

**JohnnyHK** clarified that this will not work with LINQ to Entities. For this to work you need to order *IEnumerable* instead of *IQueryable*, since *IQueryProvider* don't know how to deal with local list *IndexOf* method when it sends query to server. But after *AsEnumerable()*  *OrderBy* method deals with local data. So you can do this:

```
var entities = db.MyEntities
    .Where(e => myListOfIds.Contains(e.ID))
    .AsEnumerable()
    .OrderBy(e => myListOfIds.IndexOf(e.ID)).ToList();
```

Comment: This won't work in LINQ-to-Entities unless you chain in a call to `AsEnumerable()` before the `OrderBy`.

Answer (score 1):

Entity Framework contains a subset of all of the LINQ commands so you won't have all the commands that LINQ to Objects has.

The following approach should give you your list of MyEntities in the same order as supplied by myListOfIds:

```
var entities = myListOfIds.Join(db.MyEntities, m => m, e => e.ID, (m,e) => e)
               .ToList();
```